# str_replace not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, str-replace

I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this, but I'm construcing a mysql query from the below code. The page feeding this code is a form with checkboxes.

Depending on the checkboxes selected, I may receive the follow error:

> Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ') AND ( downloads = "download1" OR downloads = "download2"
>   OR downloads =' at line 6

The echoed query variable that I'm trying to use str_replace on based based on selecting certain checkboxes:

> SELECT url FROM crawler WHERE ( genre = "Action" OR genre =
>   "Adventure" OR genre = "Arcade" OR ) AND ( downloads = "download1" OR
>   downloads = "download2" OR downloads = "download3" OR )

Basically, I need to get rid of the final "OR" before the parentheses. The str_replace at the bottom of the code is not working. It doesn't seem to be finding the "OR )". If I cut and paste the echoed query variable into a new variable, the str_replace works fine, so I cannot see the issue with the constructed query string.

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$Action= $_GET["Action"];
$Adventure=$_GET["Adventure"];
$Arcade=$_GET["Arcade"];

$download1=$_GET["download1"];
$download2=$_GET["download2"];
$download3=$_GET["download3"];

if($Action=="true") {
  $Action='genre = "Action" OR ';
  }
  else {
  $Action="";
  }

if($Adventure=="true") {
  $Adventure='genre = "Adventure" OR '; 
  }
  else {
  $Adventure="";
  }

if($Arcade=="true") {
  $Arcade='genre = "Arcade" OR ';
  }
  else {
    $Arcade="";
    }

if($download1=="true") {
  $download1='downloads = "download1" OR ';
  }
  else {
  $download1="";
  }

if($download2=="true") {
  $download2='downloads = "download2" OR ';
  }
  else {
  $download2="";
  }

if($download3=="true") {
  $download3='downloads = "download3" OR ';
  }
  else {
    $download3="";
    }


$query = "SELECT url FROM crawler WHERE
(
$Action
$Adventure
$Arcade
)
AND
(
$download1
$download2
$download3
)";

$query = str_replace('OR )', ')', $query);
echo $query."<br>";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "Result: ".number_format($number);
echo "<br><br>";

?>
```

Comment: don't add the OR to the $Action et al string, create an array and use implode to join with or

Comment: Don't use double quotes in your query - MySQL uses single quotes to delimit strings.

Comment: @Kryten MySQL does not follow the ANSI SQL standard and allows doubles just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message doesn't show line breaks, but that doesn't mean there aren't. 
In your own definition, you write:

```
" ...
$download1
$download2
$download3
)";
```

So there is at least one line break before OR.

Try `$query = str_replace("OR \n)", ")", $query);`. You may need more or less spaces. Closely inspect the query variable before replacing, to see what exactly you need to replace.

An easier solution would be to make PHP concat the elements for you, maybe even automate it a little. Following snippet shows a possibility to have a flexible number of genres, which you can easily define in an array.

```
// Supported genres. You can get this from a database. You can also use 
// it to generate a dynamic form with.
$genres = array('Action', 'Adventure', 'Arcade');

// Get the selected genres.
$genreConditions = array();

foreach ($genres as $genre)
{
  if (array_key_exists($genre, $_GET) && $_GET[$genre] === 'true')
  {
    $genreConditions[] = "genre='$genre'"; 
  }
}

// Build a clause from it.
$genreClause = "";
if (count($genreConditions) > 0)
{
  $genreClause = '(' . implode($genreconditions, ' OR ') . ')';
}

// Do the same for downloads.
$downloadClause = "(downloads = 'download3')"; // stub

$allClauses = implode(array($genreClause, $downloadClause /*, ... others? */, ' AND ');

// Build the query

$query = 'SELECT url FROM crawler';
if ($allClauses !== '')
{
  $query .= ' WHERE ' . $allClauses;
}
```

Even better: Do it like this, but instead of concatting the string values, concat a `?` and bind a parameter. :)

Comment: Thanks. Adding the line break didn't fix it by itself, as you alluded to. I didn't realize there could be hidden values in the string. Replacing blank spaces with an underscore showed that there was a long string of hidden blank spaces, causing the str_replace not to work as written. Thanks to all reponders for the code showing how do to this correctly.

Comment: @arrogantprick A better way might be to manually build your SQL in one variable by appending to it, such as `$sql .= "WHERE ..."; `.

Answer (score 1):

Like you're using just OR, you can instead of str_replace, use Array to build the structure of your query and then use implode().

Something like this:

```
$sql = array();
if($Adventure == "true")
   $sql[] = "genre = 'Adventure'";

if($Arcade == "true")
   $sql[] = "genre = 'Arcade'";

$sql = implode(" OR ", $sql);
```

Now you can just put the contents of $sql variable on your query.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is arrays, implode function and an SQL `IN` operator. Also please note that your current query will fail if none of your conditions are true no matter if you remove `OR` or not.

```
$query = "SELECT ... FROM ...";
$genre = array();
$where = array();
if($Adventure == "true")
   $genre[] = "'Adventure'";

if($Arcade == "true")
   $genre[] = "'Arcade'";
...
if(count($genre)>0){
  $where[] = "genre IN (" + implode(",", $genre) +")";
}
...
if(count($where)>0){
  $sql += "WHERE " + implode(" AND ",$where);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to code in the way that you're doing. Imagine if you eventually have 100 genres, your PHP would be enormous.

Instead, consider these get parameters:

```
genres=Action,Adventure&downloads=1,2
```

From this, you can create a simple array:

```
$genres = explode(',', $_GET['genres']);
```

And with an array, looping is incredibly easy with `foreach`, but you can also do a simple implode:

```
$query .= implode(' OR ', $genres);
```

Just remember to escape the variables, or create a whitelist of your genres to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

This code needs refactoring :

you can use arrays in your html form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="action" />
<input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="adventure" />
```

then in the PHP side :

```
$genres = $_POST['genres'];
array_walk($genres, function(&$v, $k){
    $v = '"' . $v . '"';
});
$genres = implode(',', $genres);
```

in your SQL query :

```
'...WHERE genre IN (' . $genres . ')...'
```

same with downloads ..

and please try to use PDO instead of mysql_ functions
and don't forget to sanitize the input before making queries

Comment: While I agree a check box array makes for tidy code, he's using `$_GET`, which makes the parameters look a little untidy: `genres[]=action&genres[]=adventure`